# How do i link JSON result to Syncfusion Scheduler xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a syncfusion scheduler on my App and i need to display Json result in the schedular

```
public partial class test : ContentPage
{
    public Picker viewPicker;
    public class Data
    {
        public DateTime date_start { get; set; }
        public DateTime date_end { get; set; }
        public string salle { get; set; }
        public string professeur { get; set; }
        public string lib1_formation { get; set; }
        public string semaine { get; set; }
        public string jours { get; set; }
        public string module { get; set; }
        public string groupe_de_classe { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string remarque { get; set; }
        public string autre_professeur { get; set; }
        public string autre_groupe { get; set; }
        public string descrption { get; set; }
        public Color Color { get; set; }
    }

    public test ()
    {
        SfSchedule schedule;
        InitializeComponent();
        Calend();
        Rest();



    }

    public void Rest()
    {

        Restcours Rest_3 = new Restcours();

        Rest Student = new Rest();
        IRestResponse result_Student = Rest_3.Student("y.abasri@net.estia.fr");
        var JResponse_student = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result_Student.Content);
        Trace.Write(string.Format("Request completed in {0} ms,  Response: {1} ", 50, "ffffffffffffffffffffffff"));
        Console.WriteLine("This is the JSON RESULT --> " + JResponse_student);

        List<Data> lstData = new List<Data>();
        lstData.Add(JResponse_student.events);

        Console.WriteLine("hada houwaa --->" + JResponse_student.data.events);
    }

    public void Calend()
    {
        schedule = new SfSchedule();
        new ContentPage { Content = schedule };
        schedule.FirstDayOfWeek = (int)DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
        schedule.ScheduleView = ScheduleView.MonthView;
        MonthViewSettings monthViewSettings = new MonthViewSettings();
        monthViewSettings.AppointmentIndicatorCount = 2;
        schedule.MonthViewSettings = monthViewSettings;
    }
```

i didn't find any tutorials or docs about linking JSON to Syncfusion only the syncfusion link : https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfschedule/getting-started

Please help me out THANK YOU

Comment: you need to read the docs again, they discuss both how to use SF's built in classes to do this, as well as how to create your own custom class

Comment: Thank you @Jason Can you please specify wich line